# How to load and update entity to increment Hibernate @Version attribute?

Tags: java, hibernate

I would like to update @Version attribute of my entity without any changes in entity. This entity has as a child collections of another entity. And I would like to update the basic entity with @Version attribute to get new value of this entity version under Hibernate control. I have something like that (`attribute` isn't attribute with @Version annotation):

```
MyEntity entity = (MyEntity) getSession().load(Entity.class, id);
entity.setAttribute(new String(entity.getAttribute()));
getSession().update(entity);
```

But this is not working. The entiy has new version value only in case I am setting new value to one of its attributes. How can I load and update entity to increment Hibernate @Version attribute without any changes in that case?

Comment: Just curious. why do you the version attribute to be increased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you should have a version increment by doing a locking om your entity with a `LockMode.FORCE`:

```
Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
MyEntity u = (MyEntity) session.get(MyEntity.class, id);
session.lock(u, LockMode.FORCE);
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However lock method is deprecated I have used something like that: session.buildLockRequest(LockOptions.UPGRADE).setLockMode(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_‌​FORCE_INCREMENT).lock(u); But unfortunately I am getting this exception: `Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started`